# How do you determine if a Char is a Letter from A-Z?

Tags: vb.net

How do you determine if a letter is in the range from A-Z or Digit 0-9?  We are getting some corrupted data "I_999Š=ÄÖÆaðøñòòñ".

I thought I could use Char.IsLetterOrDigit("Š") to ID the corrupted data from "I_999Š", but unexpectedly this is returning true.  I need to trap this, any thoughts?

Comment: Of course it returns true. "Š" is a letter. Just because it isn't used in english doesn't make it a non-letter.

Comment: You also should try to fix the cause for the corruption, if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well there are two quick options. The first is to use a regular expression the second is to use the Asc() function to determine if the Ascii value is in the range of those allowable characters. I would personally use Asc() for this.

Comment: You might want to check that. I may be thinking VB6. I haven't done VB in a while.

Comment: Definitely. A-Z is ASCII 65..90, 0-9 is ASCII 48..57

Comment: The Asc() function is available in VB.NET as well, doing the same thing.

Comment: Given the context (not knowing the incoming character encoding), this answer is simply wrong.

Answer (score 12):

I can't help but notice that everyone seems to be missing the real issue:  your data "corruption" appears to be an obvious character encoding problem.  Therefore, no matter what you do with the data, you will be (mis)treating the symptom and ignoring the root cause.

To be specific, you appear to be attempting to interpret the received binary BYTES as ASCII text, when those BYTES were almost-certainly intended to represent text encoded as something-other-than-ASCII.

You should find out what character encoding applies to the string of text that you received.  Then you should read that data while applying the appropriate character encoding transformations.

You should read Joel Spolsky's article that emphasizes that ["There Ain't No Such Thing As Plain Text."](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: This answer can't get enough up votes.  Knowing the encoding of your byte stream is essential.

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches("I_999Š=ÄÖÆaðøñòòñ", "[^A-Z0-9]")
    '' Found a bad character
Next
```

or

```
For Each c As Char In "I_999Š=ÄÖÆaðøñòòñ"
    If Not (c >= "A"c AndAlso c <= "Z"c OrElse c >= "0"c AndAlso c <= "9"c) Then
        '' Found a bad character
    End If
Next
```

---

**EDIT:**

Is there something *wrong* with this answer that warrants the two anonymous downvotes?  Speak up, and I'll fix it.  I notice that I left out a "Then" (fixed now), but I intended this as pseudocode.

Comment: Aw, you can't take downvotes so personally!  One wasn't from me, btw.

Answer (score 1):

Should just be:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(input, "[A-Za-z0-9]"))
{
    // do you thang
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to ensure that you are dealing with printable ASCII characters, regardless of the encoding in the program or even in the string in question is to check each character for a legal value between 32 and 126 (127 = Delete -- not actually a 'printable' character).

i.e.

```
Public Module StringExtensions
<Extension()>

Public Function IsASCII(inString As String, Optional bPrintableOnly As Boolean = True) ' 127 = Delete (non-printing) < 32 = control characters also, non-printing

Dim lowerLimit As Int32 = If(bPrintableOnly, 32, 0)
Dim upperLimit As Int32 = If(bPrintableOnly, 127, 128)

For Each ch In inString.ToCharArray()
  If Not Asc(ch) < upperLimit OrElse Asc(ch) < lowerLimit Then
    Return False
  End If
Next

Return True

End Function
End Module
```

Comment: The encoding of a `System.String` is UTF-16 by definition.

Comment: Yes, I was going to mention that, but -- we are talking here, not about encodings, but whether or not a character (of any encoding) maps to the ASCII character set (by value only). The code snippet I posted is intended to determine if a character will cause errors downstream, which in this case is a mainframe that has no concept of characters being anything other than single byte ASCII.

These characters wind up being UTF-8 encoded and any that have the MSB set will cause processing errors, as will any ASCII control characters, hence the default lowerLimit of 32.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to filter out the bad characters ... (use Regex.IsMatch instead if you only need to detect it)

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, "[^A-Za-z0-9]","", RegexOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Asc(char) function. It returns a ANSI Character Code from 0 to 255. Check [ANSI Character Codes Chart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa245259(v=vs.60).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
NOT isNumeric(char)
```